# Updating one datepicker based on another datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi friends as i new to the jquery, i wan't to update my relieving date datepicker based on the resignation date datepicker. The relieving date datepicker should start from next 60days from the resignation date. any help will be appriciated, thanks in advance.

```
These are my two datepickers.

   $("#separetiondatepicker").datepicker({ 
        minDate: -0,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
   });

   $("#Sedatepicker").datepicker({ 
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, 
        minDate: -0 
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use jQuery UI datepicker methods Methods getDate() and setDate() to clone the value from one input field to other.

**HTML Code**

```
Resignation date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dtpik1" />
<br />
Relieving date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="dtpik2" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

Now, we can update date from 1st field to 2nd field after clicking on submit button

**jQuery Code**

```
    $( "#dtpik1" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function(dt, inst){
        var date2 = $('#dtpik1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+60);
        $( "#dtpik2" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            minDate: date2
});

        $('#dtpik2').datepicker(
                                'setDate', date2);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kk2qL7f8/3/

Comment: is it possible through onchange event??

Comment: Yes. If you want to set the date in field2 after selecting date from field1 then use onselect Option. for reference navigate to http://jsfiddle.net/kk2qL7f8/1/

Comment: i tried yo code.. but still its not effecting anything..@Divakar

Comment: i'm getting this exception.Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function .

Comment: Can I know whether you are testing this script in jsfiddle links that I have provided here

Comment: yes sir.. its working fine there but its not working my app.. i'm getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error when i'm inspecting my page..

Comment: Can I know that technologies and jquery version that you are using for you app.

Comment: i'm using visual studio web express 2013 and jquery 1.8.0.min.js

Comment: I have tested this in the same environment and it is working fine. Can you check whether you have included jquery-ui.min.js, jquery-ui.min.css files. And also make a note that you need to embed that code in $(document).ready(function(){  // Your jQuerycode goes here });

Comment: i don't know wats the problem sir, i tried everything but its still showing error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Please take a screenshot and paste here

Comment: $("#separetiondatepicker").datepicker({

                minDate: -0,

                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                onSelect: function (dt, inst) {
                    debugger;
                    var date2 = $("#separetiondatepicker").datepicker('getDate');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 60);
                    $('#Sedatepicker').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                        minDate: date2
                    });
                    $("#Sedatepicker").datepicker('setDate', date2);
                }
            });

Comment: Are you getting this issue in IE? Please test this in chrome / firefox.

Comment: @user3273883 If your query is solved then mark the answer as accepted. Always accept answer if your query is solved by clicking on correct sign...I have checked your profile asking 12 question and even not accepting one. In this way no one is going to help you further

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#startDatePicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function(date){

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000*60;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
        $("#endDatePicker").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+2y' );

    }
});


$("#endDatePicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true
});
```

[FiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/h670dy9w/)